# Adding Prefix to property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating Web API where i am in need to add prefix to property. Is it possible to prefix some text with a property in controller. For eg. I am having a class A

```
public class Stats
{
   pubic bool IsStat { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage GetStats(Stats data)
{

}
```

The Web method `GetStats` is accessed by passing data as below

```
{Stat: true}
```

Now what I need to add `Is` prefix to the `Stat` property and so i will be getting `true` value for `IsStat` property in class `Stats`. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Rename your `IsStat` property to `Stat`.  This should then match the json data.
2. Use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes on your `Stats` class and use the `IsStat` property to tell the deserializer that `IsStat` should get it's data from the `Stat` property.

```c#
[DataContract]
public class Stats
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Stat")]
    public bool IsStat { get; set; }
}
```